# Add a new data in .JSON file using angularJS

Tags: json, angularjs

I am new in angular JS. I find it quite difficult to push an object in my data.JSON file. I've read data from my .JSON file using $http.get. Is it possible to write data using $http.post? Please help me with the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot do this. Client side javascript does not have write access to files, so you'll need some kind of server support.

Comment: @MikeRobinson How can I get this server support? I want to update and delete data from my JSON file frequently. What should I do now?

Comment: That's a big question. I'd say the easiest approach, considering you're learning javascript, is to learn about node.js. There's a book, node.js the right way (https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=node.js%20the%20right%20way) that covers general setup of node and file manipulation. If you're going to manipulating JSON a lot, you should also consider using a database instead (e.g. couchDB or Mongo)

Comment: where are you serving files from in the first place?

Comment: @MikeRobinson Appreciate your suggestion and thanks again...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: @charlietfl I couldn't catch your question clearly. If you help with details I'd appreciate it very much.